# android popupwindow is above virtual keyboard

Tags: android, popupwindow, virtual-keyboard

I have a popup window with an adview appearing at the bottom or my screen.  I am doing it this way so the user can click an x to close the ad.

When the virtual keyboard comes up when the popUpWindow is active, the ad is still visible.  How can I make the keyboard take precidence over the popUpWindow or tell the popUpWindow to not be on the very top?

Answer (score 9):

You have to set `setInputMethodMode(INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED)` on the popup window before calling it, then the popup will show behind the keyboard. If you have also defined `setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)` on the popup, then it will even resize when the keyboard is hidden or shown again.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity tag in the Manifest file

Comment: This didn't work.  I should add that the popup window is called from a tabActivity, and the editText view is in one of the child tab activities.

Comment: Yes you must have added that also, try adding this in the TabActivity tag in the manifest file.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I don't believe a popupwindow can be pushed or resized by softinput.  I was able to resolve the issue by closing the popup window when the tab that has soft input was selected.  However, this is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

add to your popWindow Hieght WRAP_CONTENT

```
popWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```